# jquery images auto-loading

Tags: jquery, image, autoload

I've got this code automatically loading photos from directories which create "albums". directories are named: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 etc., photos in there 1.JPG, 2.JPG, 3.JPG and so on. I load them into div elements (tytul is a variable to store id of div which are phot1, phot2 etc). And now is my question how to hide a div when there is, for example, no image 6.JPG?

```
    var numbopht = 20;
var numbosubgals = 3;
var activegal = numbosubgals;
var leftnumber = 1;

var idnam = [];
//var idname = "#phot" + 


    var idunderline = "#subgal" + numbosubgals;  // subgal to id pozycji na liście




loadContent = function(i){

    var tytul = "#phot" + i;
var photurl = "../photos/" + activegal + "/" + i + ".JPG";
var img = $("<img />").attr({
src: photurl,
width:"120",
height:"90"

});
    $(tytul).empty().html(img);


};
```

some things that don't interact with this

```
        <div id="scrollbar">
            <div id="phot20" class="photon"></div>
            <div id="phot19" class="photon"></div>
            <div id="phot18" class="photon"></div>
            <div id="phot17" class="photon"></div>
            <div id="phot16" class="photon"></div>
            <div id="phot15" class="photon"></div>
            <div id="phot14" class="photon"></div>
            <div id="phot13" class="photon"></div>
            <div id="phot12" class="photon"></div>
            <div id="phot11" class="photon"></div>
            <div id="phot10" class="photon"></div>
            <div id="phot9" class="photon"></div>
            <div id="phot8" class="photon"></div>
            <div id="phot7" class="photon"></div>
            <div id="phot6" class="photon"></div>
            <div id="phot5" class="photon"></div>
            <div id="phot4" class="photon"></div>
            <div id="phot3" class="photon"></div>
            <div id="phot2" class="photon"></div>
            <div id="phot1" class="photon"></div>
        </div>
```

other stuff

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1:**

Use a function to check the image exists or not:

```
function imageExists(image_url){
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
http.open('HEAD', image_url, false);
http.send();
return http.status != 404;
}
```

Use a function to perform further action:

```
$.get(image_url)
.done(function() {      // Image exists at specified URL and set properties
var img = $("<img />").attr({
src: photurl,
width:"120",
height:"90"
});

}).fail(function() { // Image does not exist so Hide the Div 
   $("#tytul").hide();
})
```

**Method2:** Use `onerror` event of `img`.

```
myImage.onerror = function(){
document.getElementById("tytul").style.display = 'none';
}
```

Comment: I'm too dumb for this solution ;/

Comment: Method 2 is very easy. You just need to make an `onerror` handler for image. `onerror` is called when the image is failed to load. So inside the `onerror` handler simple set the `Display:None` to hide the **tytul** div.

Comment: @TomaszMałachowski: Here's a working example with very little code. [DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/uilve)

Answer (score 0):

Edit, updated

Try

v3

```
$("#scrollbar div[id*=phot]:not(:has(img))").hide()
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/8x9bvhnj/

Comment: It's hidden all the pictures not only the broken ones

Comment: @TomaszMałachowski See OP at , "And now is my question how to hide a div when there is, for example, no image 6.JPG?" Is requirement to hide `img` having attribute `6.JPG` , or `img` parent container ? If possible , can post `html` ? Thanks

Comment: @TomaszMałachowski Is requirement to hide entire `phot[n]` div (all images within that div), or , only single `img` having `src=6.JPG` attribute within `phot[n]` div ? Should al `photl[n]` div's contain 6 images ? Thanks

Comment: one div = one image and there is need to hide all divs that are empty and show them again when I switch sub-gallery where there are more images. The number of images can differ from 1 to 20.

Comment: @TomaszMałachowski See updated post. At updated jsfiddle , 7 div's contain images, remainder hidden. Thanks